# Get user calendar list in swift

Tags: swift, google-calendar-api

I'm new in swift and i'm trying to create a calendar app with Google Calendar Api.
I can get events from a specific calendar but i can't get a list of all user calendars. The official documentation in swift is very bad.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this may help you.. its in obj c but you can get the solution. : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-google-calendars--mobile-19155

Comment: Not sure why you are sharing the code to add a calendar event when your question is about retrieving the list of user calendars.  You should post the relevant code...